# How to use jQuery noconflict?

Tags: javascript, function, jquery

First thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526845/function-idreturn-document-getelementbyidid-blows-up-jquery

There's a conflict with my 2 JavaScript files.

I tried to use no.conflict but I don't understand which function I need to change...
my scripts loads like this

```
<script src="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath; ?>media/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath; ?>media/tags.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath; ?>js/zoom.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
$(id){return document.getElementById(id)};
</script>
<script src="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath; ?>media/pixelicious.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Config::$absolutePath; ?>media/dddropdownpanel.js"></script>
```

What's wrong, what I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `$('body').zoom({ })` at the end of the second file, this have to be changed to `jQuery('body').zoom({ })`.

Your self executing anonymous function does not cover this piece of code.

Comment: what is `function $(id){return document.getElementById(id)}`? it is a invalid javascript statement. it is at the begening of file 1

Comment: it is an invalid statement, you need to remove it

Comment: i cent remove it. that function is main for my script

Comment: but it is an invalid statement, what is it supposed to do

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use [like this.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

But if you are using something like Joomla there is some pluggins that will do all the work for you..
[This works well:](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327)

Answer (score 0):

When you use noConflict all $() that are meant to invoke jquery must become jQuery()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested:

1. Change `$.noConflict()` to `jQuery.noConflict()`.
2. In the second file change `$('body).zoom({})` to `jQuery('body').zoom({})`

Those two should solve all the problems with two files.
And remember that whenever you want to call jQuery function you have to do it with `jQuery` not `$`.